# function to check if the value is int or float but not string in PHP

Tags: php

Is there any build-in function to check the value is number, in any integral type, like int, float but not string.
is_numeric return true for "2". should I check it by both is_int and is_float?

The function that I want should return "invalid value" when $a and $b are not number:

```
function myFunction($a, $b, $sign){}
```

Comment: `$number = is_int($value) || is_float($value)`

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other number type in PHP? like double or decimal?

Comment: Why are you asking me? Read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php

Comment: `gettype( $var )` returns `double` for floats, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia I'm new to php, and training by developing some simple functions to learn. Thanks for the link.

Comment: gettype() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

Comment: `is_numeric($value) && !is_string($value)` is an alternative to the first comment.

Comment: @localheinz, after I solved my task, I noticed lots of people are using ```is_numeric($value) && !is_string($value)```, seems it is the most common way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_numeric($value) && !is_string($value)`

this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer *per se*, but this is too much to put in a comment:

```
function isFloatOrInt($var)
{
    $type = gettype($var);

    switch ($type) {
        case 'integer':
        case 'double':
            return true;
        case 'string':
            //check for number embedded in strings "1" "0.12"
            return preg_match('/^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/', $var);
        default:
            return false;
}
```

Preg match can be useful here if you consider the string version of a number to still be a number.

You say

> But not string

But does that mean this `'string'` or this `'10'` instead of `10` for example, ie. a string that is also a number?

There is probably many ways to do this, but there are some edge cases so it's largely depends on your needs.  For example is an `octet` a number to you `0777` or and exponent `12e4` or even Hexadecimal `0xf4c3b00c`?

Comment: This is definitely not the simplest solution.

Comment: No but under certain situations `is_numeric` can return a number when you don't want it to, such as `'102e8'` which it may see as an exponent.

Comment: It depends, it's not ok for say a phone number, or a zip code.  I've seen excel transform phone numbers into exponents in csv files for example.